# Do bacteria produce proteins other than ribosomal proteins when grown in wrong culture media?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

Someone I know has done an experiment using pure culture and given it to me for rna-seq analysis.

But there are a few problems

1. the bacteria she gave me as reference was initially a Staphylococcus sp. but it turned out to be Bacillus sp. Upon my analysis.
2. upon analysis I could only find ribosomal RNAs for Bacillus sp.

So my question is does a bacteria that is grown on a wrong culture media produce any proteins even in small amounts?
Will it have a lot of rRNA transcripts? Because I see all the sequencing reads map to ribosomal region. Are those not dependent on growth conditions? Or is it that Bacillus can survive on different media in a vegetative state and thus have a large number of ribosomal RNA?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, bacterial RNA-seq libraries derived from exponentially growing cells that have not been prepared using an rRNA depletion kit will result in >80% of reads mapping to 16S and 23S rRNA genes.

Ask your colleague if they used a **bacterial rRNA depletion kit** prior to RNA library preparation.

It is also my understanding that rRNA tends to be more stable than mRNA when exposed to ribonucleases given its structure and sequestration in ribosomal proteins. If your colleague performed rRNA depletion, my next hypothesis would be that the non-rRNA species were degraded due to poor technique during library preparation (samples too warm, contaminating RNase).

Comment: I will ask them and let you know the exact thing done. Thank you @acvill for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the cells are growing at all, then they are actively expressing a whole bunch of different proteins.

Ribosomal RNA, however, makes up [the vast majority of all RNA](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-23226-4) in a typical cell, however.  There are also far fewer *different* rRNAs than there are mRNAs, so the relative concentration per rRNA is even greater.

As such, unless rRNA is excluded (e.g., using methods like those described in the linked paper), the mRNA reads will typically be swamped by rRNA reads.

Comment: I am getting very few reads for other proteins. Like you said they maybe getting swamped by rRNA reads. Thank you @jakebeal for your answer.